# Fetch Remaining of The Text SwiftUI

Tags: text, swiftui, components

I was able to fetch the first paragraph of the text editor. Bu how can I fetch rest of the text?

```
TextEditor(text: $newText)
            .onChange(of: newTitle, perform: { value in
                if let firstParagraph = value.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).first {
                    selectedNote.title = firstParagraph
                }
            })
            .onChange(of: newText, perform: { value in
                if let remainingParagraph = value.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.difference(from: newTitle)) {
                    selectedNote.text = remainingParagraph
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need 1 `onChange`. I don't know what `newTitle` is, but you probably don't need it, because you only have 1 `TextEditor`.

> how can I fetch rest of the text?

[`dropFirst`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893343-dropfirst) is pretty simple:

```
String(value.dropFirst(firstParagraph.count))
```

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var totalText = "" /// text for the TextEditor
    @State var title = "" /// demo
    @State var text = "" /// demo
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $totalText)
                .onChange(of: totalText, perform: { value in
                    
                    if let firstParagraph = value.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).first {        

                        /// for demo, replace with selectedNote.title = firstParagraph
                        title = firstParagraph
                        text = String(value.dropFirst(firstParagraph.count)) /// get remaining text
                    }
                })
                .frame(height: 200)
                .border(Color.blue)
            
            Text("Title is \(title)")
            
            Text("Text is \(text)")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Entering text, which gets sorted into 2 separate Texts]